# How to iterate through 2d array starting from some position?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have to move the piece at a random position X through the whole matrix:

at every new position I compare it to the value at that position (for simplicity the only piece in the matrix is X). While doing this would be easy if X started at 0, but in my case the X piece can start at any position in the matrix, now I first started with this loop:

```
for(int i = row_x;i<rows;i++)
    for(int j = col_x;j<cols;j++)
        //do something
```

But doing that will only allow me to visit some fields: [vistied fields sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSUuJ.png)

And I need to visit all the fields highlighted in this picture:[required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDLwL.png)

So what would be the simplest way to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check if it is the first iteration of the outer loop:

```
for(int i = row_x; i < rows; i++)
  for(int j = (i == row_x ? col_x : 0); j < cols; j++)
    //do something
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to change your 2D array structure into a 1D array and work in 1D (not by an algorithm) then apply this :

```
init = rows*i+j;

for(int l = init; l<size;i++){
    //do things
}
```

Comment: " _You'd gain better algorithmic complexity too( O(n) instead of O(n²) )_ " That statement is misleading. Also you forgot that you have spent time to convert the 2D array to 1D. If the matrix has dimension `N x N` where `N = 8` then you have in 2D `O(8²)` in worst case. If you convert it first to 1D, you're doing `O(8²)` to convert it. Then you're accessing the 1D array which is in worst case ... `O(8 x 8) = O(8²)` ... So you have double work here if you use `~` notation ( 2D: `~O(8²)` vs 1D:  `~ 2 O(8²)`)

Comment: @KarelG I didn't mean to do the conversion by an algorithm, but just a suggestion for him to work on a 1D array instead of a 2D array if it isn't that necessary. and thanks too for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Do not start your inner loop (loop for column iteration from col_x, but from 0th index (first column).
This will cover the fields given in [required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDLwL.png)

Comment: You can provide a code example or place this answer as a comment.